# Create a function that has two parameters, parameter a will be a array and parameter b will find a element within the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

Was given the below to start but can't seem to figure out how to finish this. Essentially if I were to call `myTest([one, two, three], 2);` it should return the element `three`. Have to use **for-loops** to find my solution.

```
function myTest(a, b){
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
```

If I call `myTest([one, two, three], 2);` it should return the element `three`.

Assuming the above would be the correct way to call it.

Comment: do you have to use the `for` statement?

Comment: Your code is missing some parts. [mcve] please

Comment: Everyone on this thread should read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myTest(a, b){
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     if (a[i] == a[b]) {return a[i]}
  }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: The OP didn't understand anything about how to access the index values from an array.

Comment: Or maybe there was some code that needed to be executed each time until the element was found.

Comment: If that the case, the function `find` is a better solution.  The second parameter is an index, so `return a[b];` is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the index as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for the array.

```js
function myTest(array, index) {
    return array[index];
}

console.log(myTest(['one', 'two', 'three'], 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting your question then you can simply `return a[b];` without using any for loop.

Answer (score 0):

So you've to 'force' 1st parameter as an array or at least check it:

```
function myTest(arrayParam, arrayIndex) {
    if (typeof arrayParam != typeof[]) {
        console.log('wrong parameter ' + arrayParam + ' must be an Array');
        return;
    }
    return arrayParam[arrayIndex]; /** eventualy you've to check index is in array range so check the length of the array too*/
}
```

JavaScript has no typed variable so every check must be added in order to use a typed value. The typeof return type of a value wo can be object as well.

edit : even simplier and guarantee all has 'correct' type:

```
myTest(arr, idx) {
    if (arr[idx]) {
        return arr[idx];
    } //-- will simply return nothing if parameter not fit or idx out of array size
}
```

Simpler but less accurate because you can have this and still have a returned value (nothing to be sure 1st param is an array and the 2nd parameter an integer value as index):

```
myTest({test:'some value'}, 'test'); //-- who will return 'some value'
```

In 2nd example I wanna highlight that other response could not be an error and won't use array either.